# What is wrong with this piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

This piece of code of a form submission is working perfectly in Google chrome meanwhile in Firefox it does not. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    /*sending post data to php script */
    $("form[id='postForm']").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  
        var text = $('#postText').val();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        formData.append('postText', text );

        $.ajax({  
             url: "home.php?module=facebook&action=post-news&method=script",  
             type: "POST",  
             data: formData,  
             cache: false,
             processData: false,  
             contentType: false, 
             context: this,
             success: function (msg) {
                  window.location.reload();
              }
          });     
        e.preventDefault();      
    }); 

    $('input:file').on('change', function () {  
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            //Append files infos
            jQuery.each($(this)[0].files, function(i, file) {
             formData.append('imageToPost[' + i + ']', file);
            });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console in Firefox to debug the problem? Also a description of what is/is not happening would really help.

Comment: may be u using jQuery or $ at once try using $ only the check once

Comment: Did a quick check, `formData.append('imageToPost[' + i + ']', file);` is not the correct syntax for appending array of files, try this one, `formData.append('imageToPost[]', file);`

Comment: better to use $("#postForm") instead of $("form[id='postForm']")

Comment: Did you check your console and network tab in developer tool?

Answer (score 1):

Quickly checked console:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.
```

The problem is here:

```
$('input:file').on('change', function () {  
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); <--- HERE
```

*this* is not a form, but input element. Not sure what you wanted to achieve here, but probably serialize your form. For this you need to do:

```
 var form = $("#postForm")[0];
 var formData = new FormData(form);
```

And then append your file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I've figured that too

Comment: @GaelMusikingala Probably, if it's correct, it's worth to mark it as answer? Thanks.